# Using Jest and Enzyme to test functional React components that are using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-hooks

I am working on a React project and I am using functional components together with redux. I am trying to write tests for my RegisterForm component but Jest and Enzyme need a redux store.

My component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { registerRequest, registerSuccess, registerFailure } from '../redux/user/userActions';

const RegisterForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [submitDisabled, setSubmitDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitDisabled(true);
    const data = { email, password };
    dispatch(registerRequest());
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/register`, data)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(registerSuccess(res.data.auth_token));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
          dispatch(registerFailure(err.response));
        } else {
          dispatch(registerFailure(err));
        }
      });
    setSubmitDisabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor='email' className='row'>
            <div className='form-label col-form-label col-sm-2'>Email</div>
            <div className='col'>
              <input
                type='email'
                className='form-control'
                id='email'
                sm='10'
                required
                value={email}
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor='password' className='row'>
            <div className='form-label col-form-label col-sm-2'>Password</div>
            <div className='col'>
              <input
                type='password'
                className='form-control'
                id='password'
                sm='10'
                required
                value={password}
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <button
          type='submit'
          className='btn btn-primary'
          disabled={submitDisabled}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

RegisterForm.propTypes = {};

export default RegisterForm;
```

Due to React Hooks still being relatively new and people moving away from using Redux for state management I wasn't able to find a good enough question/blog post that would discuss possible ways of handling this case.

A lot of people suggest the following approach:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import RegisterForm from './components/RegisterForm'

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

const store = mockStore({
  loading: false,
  authToken: '',
  error: ''
});

const component = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RegisterForm />
  </Provider>
)
```

I would use this approach but I don't like the fact you have to mount the component. I would much rather be using *shallow* but I cannot find an implementation that uses it.

Is there any way you can use *shallow* with the stack I have going or is there some other way I could structure my component to split redux away from it so that the test doesn't need the store to be mocked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock `useDispatch`

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock(`react-redux`, () => ({
  useDispatch: jest.fn()
}));

....
 beforeEach(() => {
   useDispatch.mockClear();
 });
...
```

And slightly harder with `useSelector`:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock(`react-redux`, () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn()
}));

function mockUseSelectorWithData(mockedStore) {
  useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) => callback(mockedStore));
}

...
it('...', () => {
  const someInitialData = { ..... };
  mockUseSelectorWithData(mockedStore);
  const wrapper = shallow(<YourComp />);
  ...
  mockUseSelectorWithData(storeWithSomethingChanged);
  // changing prop or simulating event to re-render component with new data
  ....
});
```

Also beware `shallow()` does not call [`useEffect` hooks](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086) properly.

Comment: Just tried it with useDispatch and it worked! Thanks a lot!